# PHP get website contents with anchor in url

Tags: php, html, web, anchor

I can get website content but I need to simulate click on detail icon to open the "Detail" window. I tried to add `#detail=63710` to the URL but it did not work. If I load the URL with `#detail=xxxxx` in Google Chrome it shows the website with "Detail" window opened. How can I fix this?

This is my code:

```
<?php
$url='http://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?day=nov21.2016#detail=63710';

$lines_string=file_get_contents($url);

echo $lines_string;
?>
```

The result is:

[image]

But the original is:

[image]

Comment: Is that your website? (is "forexfactory.com" where the PHP file is?)

Answer (score 2):

You are making request and the html/css or javascript returned which is correct.

But the hash string is catched(#detail=63710) by javacript and after it executes it shows the difference in your results(try to disable javascript in your browser).

You can use some php library that provides browser simulation for example wait until javascript is executed and then get the html of the page.